# Power BI getting new data from a file: how could this be done better?

Tags: excel, file, powerbi, filenames, powerquery

I have a Power BI in my local folder.

I have inputs, excel files.

When I have a new input with new data, in the form of a new excel file, I only care about these new data. I do not care about anything data in the past file.

Currently, when I receive a new excel input:

1. I change the name of the excel file giving it the same name as the file that it will replace.
2. I suppress the old excel file in the folder where it is stored
3. I replace it with the new excel file, with the name of the old one in the folder of the old excel file

To provide a concrete example, here is my folder with two files and my power bi:

[image]

If I have a new file with corresponding to the "Rabbit employed by Batman", I supress this excel file in the folder.
I change the name of my new excel input, calling it "Rabbit employed by Batman".
I replace it in the folder with the Power BI.

I feel that this might not be very clever, and I wonder if there is a better way to proceed.

Comment: To me your current approach makes sense and I see nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering if it was possible to go "a step futher" in one way or the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Power Query use excel from folder, sort by date and choose the latest one, If you have more than one file with the same name, create an Index,  rank over filename sort descending and use the number 1 as your binary source.

Comment: Hi! Thank you! I do not understand this part "In Power Query use excel from folder, sort by date and choose the latest one" but I am going to do some tests and refine my question if needed! Thank you!

Comment: From the Power BI Menu:    HOME = > GET DATA => FOLDER

Comment: This solution makes sense, but it's really important to don't edit any (old) file in the folder, otherwise, you will get data from the wrong file. you could set the excels as read-only files to ensure that no edit is made